# How to calculate the expected value on this example, part b, only.

Tags: probability, statistics

A girl scout troup has 100 boxes of cookies to sell. Of these 100 boxes 60 are chocolate chip and 40 are sugar cookies. 10 boxes are randomly selected to be sold at a fair.

(a) What is the probability that of the 10 selected boxes 5 are chocolate chip? What distribution are you using and what are the parameters?

x is and Hypergeometric (10,60,100)
I calculated P(X=5)=0.207

(b) If the chocolate chip can be sold for 3 dollars and the sugar cookies for 2 dollars, what is the expected value and standard deviation of the amount of money the girl scouts will make at the fair (assume that all 10 selected boxes will be sold).

My problem is how to calculate this expected value and standar deviation?

I know that the expected value is n M/N for an hypergeometric random variable.
but I can not figure it out how to calculate for all the cases? the book said the value is e(x)=26 dollars and 1.48 for the standar desviation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(a) is correct. You have a hypergeometric distribution and $\mathsf P(X=5)= \dfrac{\binom{60}{5}\binom{40}{5}}{\binom{100}{10}} \\ \approx 0.20760568129294877582176382662575\cdots$

---

For (b): If you sell $x$ chocolate chip and $10-x$ sugar cookies, then you make $20+x$ dollars.

Then the expected value is: $\mathsf E(20+X) = 20+\sum\limits_{x=0}^{10} \dfrac{x\binom{60}{x}\binom{40}{10-x}}{\binom{100}{10}} \\ = 20 + \frac{10\cdot 60}{100} \\ = 26$

Similarly, if you know the variance of the hypergeometric is $\mathsf {Var}(X) = 10 \frac{60}{100}\frac{40}{100}\frac{100-10}{100-1}$, then you know the variance of the earnings.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $X$ be the r.v. of number of chocolate chip in the 10 selected box and $Y$ be the money the girl scouts will make given all 10 selected box are sold.

$X \sim \mathrm{Hypergeometric} (10,60,100)$

$Y = 3X + 2(10-X) = X + 20$

Then, calculate $E(Y)$, $Var(Y)$ and $SD(Y)$

$$E(Y) = E(X+20) = E(X) + 20$$

$$Var(Y) = Var(X+20) = Var(X)$$

$$SD(Y) = \sqrt{Var(Y)} = \sqrt{Var(X)}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**(first part):-

You know $p(a)=\frac {favourable-outcomes}{total-outcomes}$

Total outcomes here is the number of ways in which $10$ boxes can be selected from $100$ boxes.

Favorable outcomes are the number of ways in which $5$ boxes can be selected out of $60$ boxes.

Use $n\choose r$ formula to solve the above.